# NavMesh Sample position returns infinity

Tags: unity-game-engine, vector, navmesh

Im trying to get a random position that im sure is on the nav mesh. I use SamplePosition to give me the closes on mesh position on the nav mesh by calling another method that generates a random position that is sure within the screen field.

I try this several times but mostly i get a postion Vector3(infinity,infinity,infinity)

```
    public static Vector3 RandomMapPosition()
{
    Vector3 pos = new Vector3(Random.value, Random.value, Camera.main.transform.position.z);
    var searchPosition = Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(pos);

    return searchPosition;
}


public static Vector3 RandomNavMeshPosition()
{
    var randomPos = RandomMapPosition();

    NavMeshHit hit;
    NavMesh.SamplePosition(RandomMapPosition(), out hit, 1.0f, NavMesh.AllAreas);
    return hit.position;
}
```

Comment: Random.value returns a random number between 0.0 [inclusive] and 1.0 [inclusive]. Also how are you sure that pos is on the navmesh?

Comment: I suggest you this tho.
http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/475066/how-to-get-a-random-point-on-navmesh.html

Comment: Getting infinity back means that the supplied point never corresponded to a point on the nav mesh.